# Find the functions family that satisfies the inequality $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+f^{2}(x)} <\frac{f(1)}{f'{(1)}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I wonder what is the functions family that satisfies the following inequality:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+f^{2}(x)} <\frac{f(1)}{f'{(1)}}$$

This inequality seems to be a very interesting inequality, but not sure when it works and when not. For example, it works if i take $f(x)=e^x$ that is
$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+e^{2x}} = 0.28 < 1.$

Comment: Why is it an interesting inequality?

Comment: @Mercy: because there are many calculus problems where you need to prove that a similar integral to this one is smaller than a certain value. It would help me solve many of these problems. Usually, it's rather hard to prove such inequalities and such a generalization is welcome ( of course, for some functions only).

Comment: Here's my first though: If we assume that:
$f'$ is continuous and not increasing; $f'(1) \neq 0$; $f(0) = 0$; $f(1) \ge 0$, than:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{f'(x)}{1 + f^2 (x)} \cdot \frac{dx}{f'(x)} \le \frac{\arctan f(1)}{f'(1)} \le \frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}$$

Comment: You could try to find functions $u$ satisfying $$J(u):=\int_0^1[1+u^2(x)]^{-1}dx-u(1)/u'(1)=a$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @qoqosz: it seems your way works just fine.

Comment: @qoqosz If $f$ is not increasing, isn't $0=f(0) \ge f(1) \ge 0$, i.e. $f(1)=0$?

Comment: @Mercy it is derivative which is not increasing.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that: $f'$ is continuous and not increasing; $f'(1) \neq 0$; $f(0) = 0$; $f(1) \ge 0$, than:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{f'(x)}{1 + f^2 (x)} \cdot \frac{dx}{f'(x)} \le \frac{\arctan f(1)}{f'(1)} \le \frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}$$